# I am new to node js and backend as a whole. how do i use the value of the variable called "cut" outside the app.get function in another function

Tags: node.js, global-variables

```js
app.get("/search", async function (req, res) {
  const searchString = req.query.search;
  cut = searchString.slice(24);
});
console.log(cut);
```

Comment: Your `console.log` get execute before you do a http request. You can use the value only inside the callback. Thats how asynchron code execution works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable outside of the function as below,

```js
let cut;

app.get("/search", async function (req, res) {
  const searchString = req.query.search;
  cut = searchString.slice(24);
});

console.log(cut);
```

Problem with this though, is that your `console.log(cut);` will run the moment you load the javascript file and it will NOT be run every time you make your HTTP call to to GET /search.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but i tried the above it didn't work. i will try use another method, afterall thats what programming is all about. thanks

Comment: This does not work because console.log gets executed befor your route handler. Therefore is cut undefined.

Comment: Yes, it wont work. As I mentioned in the answer - the console.log(cut) is being run when the file is loaded(before your route handler is being called) and not within the route.